# IE 8 & 9 ignoring div width -  how to get this example to work?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, doctype

The following html page seems to render fine in any browser but IE 8 & 9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 300px">

        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="test" />Choice 1
        </span>
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="test" />Choice 2
        </span>
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="test" />Choice 3
        </span>
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <input type="radio" value="4" name="test" />Choice 4
        </span>
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <input type="radio" value="5" name="test" />Choice 5
        </span>
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <input type="radio" value="6" name="test" />Choice 6
        </span>
        <span style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <input type="radio" value="7" name="test" />Choice 7
        </span>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The html seems fairly straight forward, but IE 8 & 9 ignore the width on the div and force all choices on the same line (IE 7 and all other non-IE browsers wrap at 300px as they should). Somehow I need this radio button list to wrap at a specified width while not separating the radio from the corresponding choice.

I can get IE 8 & 9 to behave if I change the doctype, however I'd like to avoid changing that if possible.

I get the same behavior if I use the old-school "nobr" tags in place of the span tags.

Comment: does adding a `display: inline-block;` style to your div help?

Comment: you can always add float:left;clear:both; to the spans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should put  "`;`"  in `<div style="width: 300px;">` (good practice )

use `display: inline-block`; instead of `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: The last `;` in a style declaration and in CSS blocks is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  "display: inline-block" did the trick. The semicolon shouldn't be required at the end of an inline style, however, but it's probably cleaner to do so anyway.

Comment: @Mayankswami You should update your first statement. It's not true that IE 8 and 9 ignore the inline style declaration in the absense of a closing semi-colon.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the tabs and newlines that you have in your  markup. You're asking IE to not wrap on these, yet at the same time asking each element to remain narrow enough to sit side-by-side in the parent container.

You'll note that if you remove the white-space, all browsers render the markup the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div { 
        width: 300px; 
        border: 1px solid #333
      }
      span { 
        border: 1px solid red; 
        white-space: nowrap
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span><input type="radio" value="1" name="test" /> Choice 1</span>
      <span><input type="radio" value="2" name="test" /> Choice 2</span>
      <span><input type="radio" value="3" name="test" /> Choice 3</span>
      <span><input type="radio" value="4" name="test" /> Choice 4</span>
      <span><input type="radio" value="5" name="test" /> Choice 5</span>
      <span><input type="radio" value="6" name="test" /> Choice 6</span>
      <span><input type="radio" value="7" name="test" /> Choice 7</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, the question wasn't how to get IE to render it correctly, the question was how to get IE to render it correctly **with the doctype in the original post**, which your example doesn't have.  "display: inline-block", suggested by Mayank, works with both your doctype, and the original doctype.

Comment: @TroyEvans: When I tested Jonathan's posted Html usign your DocType `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
` it still worked in IE. See here for DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/eHwm5/3/

Comment: @TroyEvans Change the doctype; it still works in IE. Your instruction to IE was inconsistent - the doctype is irrelevant here.

Comment: +1 for a very good explanation on how `nowrap` works in IE and demonstrating how code formatting effects this.

Comment: @JonthanSampson Sorry for speaking too soon. You are correct that your code works with either doctype. I am curious, though, why my original code works if I _remove_ the doctype, but won't work with the doctype that is there. It seems the doctype isn't completely irrelevant.

Comment: @TroyEvans Removing the doctype puts your document into Quirks mode, where *anything goes*. Don't go there, it's a place of lawlessness and rebellion. Nobody survives its evil streets. Convicts and psychopaths wait around every corner - your children aren't safe. ;)